# how to use haproxy for aws elastic service

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, haproxy

This is my haproxy:

```
frontend es_front
   bind 127.0.0.1:9200
   mode tcp
   option tcplog
   default_backend es_backend

backend es_backend
       mode tcp
       option tcplog
       balance roundrobin
       server es-1 vpc-es-.eu-central-1.es.amazonaws.com:443 check ssl verify none
```

Here is my error:

```
curl -XGET 'https://127.0.0.1:9200/_cluster/health?'
curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
```

So how do I deal with ES on aws with haproxy?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`ssl verify none` tells HAProxy to terminate the TLS session toward the back-end.  If this is used, but the front end does not also have `ssl` on the `bind` line, then you are telling HAProxy to return cleartext, not TLS, back to the browser.

Remove `ssl verify none` ... or access the proxy with HTTP, not HTTPS, in your curl URL.